# Can I overlay lumber perpendicular to floor joists to raise the floor height?

Tags: floor, joists

We have put our 2x6s joists down in our bathroom that is 2.45m by 1.45m.

We realized that we are short by about 8cm, so we were thinking, is it a bad idea to put 2 by 6s flat I.e the 6 going horizontal, the 2 going vertical, perpendicular to how the joists are at the moment? Or is this not allowed? And if so, is there a required span?

Plywood and tiles will go on top of this as it’ll be a wetroom.

Please see the picture below.

Also, when I said 2x6s flat I mean like this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry the images came up weird but, the 2x6s (main ones) are going horizontally , I.e the 2.45m. But with the shower former ply and tiles we’ll be short by 8-10cm, so that’s why we wanted to maybe increase the floor by adding 2 inches more and getting thicker ply, hence the idea of laying down the remaining 2x6s with have but vertically and also with the 6inch side laying flat on the other joists

Comment: We can use 2 5/4 plywoods stacked on top (is there a protocol for this) but is it ok to then add the other 22mm ply to be flush with the shower tray? That’s a lot of ply so don’t know if that would be ok or not..

Comment: Potentially even 3 5/4 plywood’s and an 22mm ply... isn’t that a lot of plywood?... I don’t mind, I’m just wondering if the floor can take it

Comment: I do not think there are any rules against making it much stronger then it needs to be. The other option is to raise the ledger board joist unit and re-anchor it at the height you need, *minus the sub floor thickness of coarse*.

Comment: Yeah... tbh the bolts are chemically inserted and it’s gonna be hell on earth to redo it all. If having that much ply is feasible then I might just go with that. When stacking ply, are there any issues we need to bear in mind? Any specific layout of them I.e with joints etc?

Comment: @SuzanAydın I thought all floorboards were horizontal by definition (bah dum cha!)

Answer (score 9):

I would say that the main issue with putting down boards like that is cupping or bowing of the wood especially since this is a high moisture area; that's dirt beneath the joists, right? Look at any wooden deck and you will quickly see what I mean by bowing or cupping.

Additionally if you haphazardly layout the boards like that then there will obviously be unsupported areas which will sag as soon as someone steps on it.

I recommend furring up the floor joists by using a table saw to rip 2 inch pieces of wood and attach them directly to the top of the joist.

If you don't have a table saw then you should be able to buy furring strips directly from a lumber yard or supply store.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - it’s a good one. How do you feel about my suggestion in Alaska Man’s comment?

Comment: @SuzanAydın If you're in the mood to rip out the 2x6 joists and replace with 2x9 joists then that is 100% up to you; It will certainly be the sturdiest bathroom floor you've ever walked on. Just make sure to also replace the ledger boards and rim joists or apply furring strips to those. However if you're going through all this trouble then it almost seems easier to lift the entire floor by mounting the ledger boards higher on the wall.

Comment: Houses have used wide boards as flooring or subflooring for centuries. As a subfloor, the boards are usually run on a diagonal, not perpendicular to the joists, but I'm not certain why. Of course, old-growth hardwood wood that was used 100+ years ago was much more warp resistant than modern fast grown pine, but still, it was used.

Comment: @FreeMan Sure OP can install 2x6 subflooring if they want but I can immediately imagine some considerations: cost, buckling, good luck to your wrist when you have to use a hole saw for the plumbing, it looks like dirt below the joists so cupping and bowing could come into play still. Fwiw, my 1940 house has diagonal board subfloor but it's only 3/4" thick so I am well aware of how things used to be, hah.

Comment: @SuzanAydın Any thoughts on how you will proceed?

Comment: We actually decided to just swap the 2x6 joists with 2x9 and kept the 2x6 rim joists... not our proudest moment but... we’ll support with noggins and such...

Comment: @SuzanAydın Nothing wrong with that. Just make sure to fur up the ledgers and rim joists to the same height!

Comment: Sweet. I guess I could lay a 2x3 on each rim joist. Shall I just screw them through the horizontal joists at a 45 degree angle? Don’t know if I should screw directly vertically down the 2x3 into the rim joist and by how much

Comment: @SuzanAydın I would lay down wood glue or construction adhesive or wood adhesive, put the furring strip on top, clamp down, and use 3" or 4" trim screws to secure the strips. The 3" trim screw can be driven down through the furring strip to catch the joist on the other side. If you're using an adhesive that can withstand expansion and contraction then you can remove the trim screws after the glue cures so that they don't get in the way of securing the subfloor. I suggestion trim screws because they are less likely to split the furring strip.

Comment: If the strip is 3 inches thick, should I get 4 inch screws?

Comment: @SuzanAydın Yes, get 4 inch screws. The only reason I mentioned 3 inch trim screws is that they'll have uses beyond this project whereas 4 inch screws are rarely appropriate besides this specific project.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question directly... **yes, you can overlay lumber like that**. Modern engineered trusses have 2x4 top chords that span greater distances than you have here.

However, it's a bit of a waste. You'd be better off ripping those boards to the exact dimension you need to raise the floor and laying them directly on each of your existing joists. Screw them down well and move on.

Multiple layers of plywood would be a waste of time and money, assuming they don't benefit you in preparing for tile installation.

Comment: Can I keep the 2x6 rims Isherwood and just have my horizontal joists as 2x8 instead of 2x6?

Comment: @SuzanAydın IIUC, you're wanting to shim up the "field" but not the rim joists. That's a bad idea, because now the edges of the room will be 2" short. Shim up _all_ of your flooring system to the desired height, add the subfloor, the interior, then the finish floor.

Comment: Realistically your subfloor would span the 1-1/2" gap, but it may be a big spongy between joists.

Comment: @isherwood noggins between joists could help right?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative would be to swap the rim joists to 2x8.  You don't need to remove the bolts from the masonry wall to do it.  You just have to un-fasten the nuts which hold the 2x6 rim joist on the bolt.

I imagine that's what you would have done originally if there wasn't a miscalculation.  May as well consider this re-work option against the others (furring the joists up, etc.)

Comment: Purchasing a few new 2x8's seems to be the easiest & cheapest way to go.

Comment: Do you reckon I could just put 2x8/2x9 joists in my joist hangers and still use 2x6 rim joists?

Comment: Don't change the floor joists; just the rim joists.  Position the hangers so the floor joists and rim joists create a level surface at the appropriate height for the subfloor.  The rim joists will hang down further and that's okay.  If you look at some outdoor decks, you'll see rim joists which are maybe 2x10 or 2x12 and smaller 2x6 joists are usually fastened to them.  Basically that's what I suggest in the bathroom; change the rim joists only.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Not to sound like someone banging on but... if you do a 2x6 ledger with 2x8 joists, is this bad? Just curious if it is and why... if it’s also better to have the joists notched to go across the 2 inch of ledger etc...

Comment: Also, we could instead (still hoping you’ll give an answer to what i said above - pretty please ), Lay 2 by 4 flat so 4 is laid across and only 2 up.

Then, lay 18mm plywood across whole thing

Then put shower tray on top of plywood, cut out necessary bit of ply for drain

Lay 22mm plywood to fit flush as shower tray is 22mm

Add tile adhesive and tiles for extra 13mm

Totals 100mm

Comment: @SuzanAydın Use 2x8 rim joists to raise the rim to the desired height (i.e. drill the mounting bolt holes off center). Then rehang all your existing 2x6 joists at the _top_ of the new 2x8 rim joists. There is absolutely _no_ problem with this system. There is _no_ requirement that all floor framing material be the same height, just that each individual piece be _at least_ strong enough for its role. If 2x6s are strong enough, then 2x8s are _at least_ strong enough (since they'll be stronger).

Comment: @SuzanAydın "if you do a 2x6 ledger with 2x8 joists" you've got that exactly backwards. You'll have 2x8 ledgers with 2x6 joists.

Comment: My other half went with 2x6 rim joists (left them there) and 2x8 joists. Hopefully this won’t cripple the floor... this is for a disabled person so we have only 3 days left to do absolutely everything else.... was a big task... and tbh it may not be the right thing to do, but I’m hoping that with the bathroom only being 1.47m by 2.3m the floor won’t collapse....

Comment: I can't think of anything wrong with the 2x8 joists connected to 2x6 rim-joists/ledgers.  They might be less-resistant to twisting in the joist hangars; a common solution to that is to add some blocking.  If you haven't already installed the subfloor, a piece of blocking between each pair of joists might be a good precaution, and you could re-use scraps for it.

Comment: That sounds good Jeff thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would put down a combination of plywood and cement board that will give you the height you need for your tile to be at the correct level.

Start with a layer of 1 1/8" ply screwed into the joists. 1 1/8" is very strong and thick so whatever you put down on top of it can be fastened to it and not necessarily to the joists. Layers of 3/4" ply would also work if you can not get 1 1/8". *Be aware that the actual dimensions of plywood are not the stated dimensions, 1 1/8" is closer to 1" thick as 3/4 is really 5/8"*.

On top of that would be a combination of plywood and cement board to equal the dimension you need to place your sub-floor at the proper height for your tile.

For a room this small i do not think you need to install the second layer of ply perpendicular to the first, but you can, just do not put one seam on top of another seam.

Comment: What is 5/4" plywood? I've never seen that in stores, but it sounds _very_ expensive.

Comment: Or.... I was thinking, instead of the 2x6 horizontal joists, can I replace it with 2x9s? The joist hangers can take them. They obviously be higher than the ledgers but this shouldn’t be a problem?

Comment: @isherwood  There are 4  quarters in an inch, 5/4 is  1 1/4". I have seen 5/4 tongue and groove used for floor decking in new construction. Lowes carries 1 1/8".

Comment: @SuzanAydın There are a few ways to "skin this cat"

Comment: I know what 5/4 means. I've installed more 5/4 lumber than most people have walked on. I haven't heard of plywood referred to using that term, and the product you mentioned at Lowes costs nearly three times what 3/4 does. Not a great solution, in my opinion.

Comment: @isherwood - I figured you knew what 5/4" was, just a little tongue and cheek.  I edited my answer to be about the more common 1 1/8 plywood.